# GCC -l (link library option) showing same output when not linked

Tags: c++, gcc

I have question about gcc compiler link library option. 
I an running gcc compiler from docker container.
when I try to compile by typing in 
"gcc -Iinclude -Llib_x86 *.c *.h -o main",

output shows following :
undefined reference to "secure_ClearStream" 
undefined reference to "proc_readProcess"
undefined reference to "proc_getOutput"
.. (and 16 more functions from both secure.a and proc.a library)

and then I tried linking library option using -l by typing in  
"gcc -Iinclude -Llib_x86 *.c *.h -o main -l:secure.a -l:proc.a"

it shows following as well

output shows following :
undefined reference to "secure_ClearStream" 
undefined reference to "proc_readProcess"
undefined reference to "proc_getOutput"
.. (and 16 more functions from both secure.a and proc.a library)

which is exactly same. compiler does not throw error about linking library, and it is pretty weird why it still is not finding function description if it successfully linked library. 
I am pretty sure library exist in "lib_x86" directory, and I'd like to understand why it is happening.

I'd like to screenshot output but I can't tell you more detail due to security issue. For those who have already faced similar situation, can you share your experience?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are the names of physical library files?  Standard would be `libproc.a` and `libsecure.a`, but you seem to be trying to link them as if they were named without the "lib" prefix.

Comment: Also, why are you compiling headers?  One should not designate header files on the compilation command line (though usually it is just wasteful, not genuinely harmful).

Comment: yeah, library names are "proc.a", "secure.a". I went through file conversion process, so it i s not following standard naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for information about not compiling headers. I didn't know that.

Comment: What "file conversion process"?  That sounds pretty fishy, especially if it ends up emitting files with nonstandard names.

Comment: Well, so my team has been programming C/C++ using resources (.dll, .lib) supported from NI (national instrument). Apparently those file types are only runnable with 'Visual Studio" compiler, and we actually confirmed it working properly with visual studio IDE. When we transitioned from visual studio to MinGW compiler, because MinGW compiler is not compatible with .lib and .dll file types, we went through conversion process that converts .dll and .lib extension to .a extension to run project with compatible resources in gcc/g++. So that's why our libraries do not have lib prefix.

Comment: I worried if library files were corrupted during conversion, but I looked into our generated .def file and confirmed function names matching exactly with original functions from documentation

Comment: I would also be worried about the conversion, but I think there is something else strange here, because [MinGW can both generate and link against DLLs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html).  I think you would be well advised to make use of that instead of trying to modify third-party library binaries.

Answer (score 0):

The way you specified the libraries, as well as how they are named, is incorrect:

```
-l:secure.a -l:proc.a
```

There is no `:` after the `-l` option.  Also, `-l` expects files to have a particular name.  So if you pass `-l mylib`, it looks for a file named `libmylib.a`.  You're passing in the full file name, and these names also don't fit that naming convention.

You can either pass the name of the library files without `-l`:

```
g++ -Iinclude -Llib_x86 *.c *.h -o main secure.a proc.a
```

Or you can rename them to libsecure.a and libproc.a and use `-l` like this:

```
g++ -Iinclude -Llib_x86 *.c *.h -o main -l secure -l proc
```

Comment: The form `-l:filename` is meaningful to the GNU linker, so actually, yes, sometimes there **is** a colon after the `-l`.  But that is nevertheless a good hypothesis for where the problem resides in this case.

Comment: I tried compiling without -l, and it still showed exactly same output, undefined reference to <function_name>. I wonder if there is problem with my library files.

Comment: Are all your files C as opposed to C++?  If so use gcc instead of g++.  Same when compiling the libraries.